# how can we make different urls referring to same domains work on same cookie and session

Tags: session

I have a website www.abc.com and i have a user for whom the url is name.abc.com.
Then what is the procedure to use the same session for both the urls

Answer (score 1):

To create a domain wide cookie you have to set it's domain to ".example.tld" or in your case ".abc.com". In PHP you can do this e.g. with:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.abc.com');
```

Cookie based sessions should then be available across all subdomains.

Best wishes,
Fabian

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a single best approach. You might want to read this SO post:
[What’s your favorite cross domain cookie sharing approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263010/whats-your-favorite-cross-domain-cookie-sharing-approach)

And [Googled results](http://www.google.com.sg/search?q=cross+domain+cookies)

Answer (score 0):

In order for cookies to be shared between subdomains, the cookie domain must be `.abc.com`. Setting the cookie domain varies between different programming languages/frameworks.