# ASP.NET Access cookies from different domains

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I'm working on a website where the same instance runs across multiple domains (and not just sub-domains).

Is it possible to create a cookie thats accessible across all of these domains?
Similar to the way facebook cookies work from everywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only for subdomains in the same root domain - you can use wildcard cookies by just specifying the subdomain. ex. sv1.test.com sv2.test.com all would use test.com

see:
http://forums.asp.net/t/369569.aspx/1

For using a single cookie cross root domain - you cannot do this. It breaks the rules of trust - otherwise my app could read your other cookies. What happens in sites that 'seem' to share cookies is there is usually a redirect to that other domain to validate a value and then a redirect back to the other domain. Values can then be posted over, set in hidden form fields or the querystring.

Also see this quasi duplicate post:
[Sharing cookies across different domains and different applications (classic ASP and ASP.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781353/sharing-cookies-across-different-domains-and-different-applications-classic-asp)

Comment: ahh, I thought this was the case. Thanks for clearing that up.
Looks like Facebook use iframes and redirects for this.

Answer (score 0):

Could you have .js functions on `CommonSite.com` that store and retrieve the cookies?

So you might have `commonSite.com/CookieMonster.js`

Then on :

`FirstDomain.com/MyPage.htm`  you could call `commonsite.com/cookiemonster.js`'s   `SaveCooke(CookieValue)`

Same on `SecondDomin.com/OtherPage.htm`