# backbonejs cookie not maintained across cross domains

Tags: javascript, session, backbone.js, cookies

I have a backbone marionette application that makes REST api calls.

In my model when i make a api call to login i get a session value back and see the cookie being set in the browser

immediately after when i make another call to get the user information that is logged in i receive a different session or cookie value and no user is found. CORS is enabled and options calls are being made.

When i hook up the api to my other applications that were build off non backbone libraries it works fine. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Here is my post

```
         doLogin: function( data ){

            this.fetch({
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',


                error:(function (e) {
                    alert('error');
                })
            });

        },
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear on this piece of code but looks like your calls are going to different domains (once you mentioned CORS).

If that is really the case, I am afraid session and cookie might be different because they are probably specific only to the domain that your 1st request (`doLogin`) reached but not the 2nd request (`fetch`). More info: [Sharing cookies across different domains and different applications (classic ASP and ASP.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781353/sharing-cookies-across-different-domains-and-different-applications-classic-asp)

Another thing to look is if your both servers REALLY support CORS because one part of the setup is client-side and another is server-side (headers). More info on: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/