# ASP.NET cross domain authetication with server side created cookies

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, cross-domain

Can I manually create and add cookies for multiple domains (in HttpResponse.Cookies) on the server and return them to the browser ? If yes does it mean that content for the domains I've create cookies for can see that cookie ? **Not** talking about sub-domains but different domains all together. So I create cookie for a.com , b.com, c.com and then I return them to the client, then I open iframes to their sites ... will this work or do the browser override the domain if its not the one they received the cookies from ?

**EDIT**: I guess it doesn't work? The browser is overriding it:(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263010/whats-your-favorite-cross-domain-cookie-sharing-approach