# it's possible to set a cookies to another domain with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I tried it with jQuery:

```
$.cookie('test', 'value', { expires: 7, path: '/', domain: 'test.com' });
```

but it won't work.

it's possible to do?

Comment: I'm guessing it won't work for a very good set of reasons, not the least of which is that being able to spoof cookies from another domain is a gaping security hole.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible but I would be really surprised if you could! That would be a serious flaw!

Comment: Can you do it using delphi from within the browser without the user being asked to execute an application on their local computer?  Again, I'm guessing no.

Comment: There is a difference between code running in an application on your computer and code running in a webpage loaded from a website you visited. A big difference.

Answer (score 12):

Nope, that will not work for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do due to security reasons.

if you are in control of the 2nd domain there are some options to share your cookies described already here:
[What's your favorite cross domain cookie sharing approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263010/whats-your-favorite-cross-domain-cookie-sharing-approach/590411#590411)

Comment: That still won't work unless there is some passing of state over GET (e.g. a nonce that identifies the user).

Comment: @alex i edited my answer cause i didn't describe it properly. possibilities to share a cookie cross domain were already answered elsewhere so linked that question what is saying about the same thing as i meant :)

Answer (score 1):

Due to many people abusing it, most browsers block 3rd party either by default or by the user setting such a preference.

From [Cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html):

> Each cookie also has a domain and a
>   path. The domain tells the browser to
>   which domain the cookie should be
>   sent. If you don't specify it, it
>   becomes the domain of the page that
>   sets the cookie, in the case of this
>   page www.quirksmode.org. Please note
>   that the purpose of the domain is to
>   allow cookies to cross sub-domains. My
>   cookie will not be read by
>   search.quirksmode.org because its
>   domain is www.quirksmode.org . When I
>   set the domain to quirksmode.org, the
>   search sub-domain may also read the
>   cookie.
>   **I cannot set the cookie domain to a domain I'm not in, I cannot make the
>   domain www.microsoft.com . Only
>   quirksmode.org is allowed, in this
>   case.**