# Automatically login to current website if user is logged in to another website

Tags: php, asp.net, session, authentication, asp-classic

I have about 100 websites coded in ASP classic. Each website accepts orders and stores them in database. However, the payment of these orders must be made on another website, also coded in ASP classic. All websites are owned by same company, hosted on same IIS server and use the same SQL Server database.

Now, the user registers by entering some personal information and logs in to one of these website (e.g. website-for-newjersey.com) and places an order. He is then redirected to the payments website (payments.master-website.com on https) where some of his personal information  (address, city, state for shipping; name for credit card holders name; etc) appears on the payment form. Credit card specific information is entered on that page.

Because of the sensitivity of information shown on that page, the user must login to the payment website before he/she can view the *pre-filled* payment form. And I do not want the user to login twice (once on each website). Is there a reliable way of checking if the user is logged in to the *referring* website using classic ASP.

---

**Long story short**

- On website B I need to check if the visitor is logged into website A
- On website B I need the ID session variable from website A
- Both websites use same database server
- I need clear instructions
- PHP or ASP.NET solution is acceptable if it is generic/portable

Comment: why don't you go with roberts suggestion? it's an excellent approach and you cannot share session between different domains, otherwise you would be able to steal someones facebook session or something. Whenever you are about to pay, do as robert said. store a random string in your database related to that user. Encrypt it, go over SSL to your new website, decrypt it and check for the user in the database. Also check with time (like within 1-2 minutes after creation)

Comment: Have you heard of something called session bridge?

Comment: @TechGirl: no I have not.

Comment: Since this is sensitive information, I would consider saving the session state in database and accessing the same from another application if it seems feasible. Else for nonsensitive ones, cookie is an option.

Comment: @TechGirl: this idea is correct. But for that I need a method to find which two sessions belong to same browser user/browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you asked is called single sign on (SSO) and can be implemented in few ways. There are many topics on this matter, example: [What's your favorite cross domain cookie sharing approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263010/whats-your-favorite-cross-domain-cookie-sharing-approach) but they all vary due to individual requirements.

In your case you have different domains (so you cannot share cookies across them), you mix http and https (which might be a problem) and you have many applications so you won't make many changes.

So I would recommend to consider Robert's suggestion:

1. When user is authenticated for the first time (website A) you save a GUID in the database. Add a new table for sessions with columns for GUID, userid, ip and timestamp or save it as a part of orders data. Store GUID in the session object.
2. On the page that had a link to the payment site set it in the query string or as a hidden variable (if it's a form).
3. On the other domain (website B) check for the GUID and then look it up in the database.  If it wasn't too old then authenticate the user, otherwise redirect him to a login page.

If you cannot change a link to the payment site then you could try to skip the step 2 and  validate the user by his ip but this might be too risky.

Comment: This looks simple. However, what happens if someone copies a legitimate token from website A, open website B in another browser/computer and post the token?

Comment: A combination of (validate IP + check referer + use POST) should do it. You can also remove the GUID from the database when user was validated so same GUID (url) cannot be used again.

Comment: @SalmanA : you do not save the GUID. Rather you save *and update* a *random UUID* generated each time by the source site upon the redirect. Then you purge the UUID from the DB upon receiving it on the target site. This means that your mischievous user would have to *block* his own redirect (otherwise the UUID would be deactivated), **and** must copy and post the GUID from another computer within, say, 5 seconds. A normal 302 Redirect does not take this long, so all UUIDs older than a very few seconds may safely be deemed invalid.

Answer (score 9):

From the calling site you could create a guid or some other randomly generated value.  Store it on the users record (set to expire in a specified time period) in the database, encrypt it and pass it over SSL to the payment site where it is decrypted and then compared to the database.  If they match then the user is logged in, if it doesn't match then they are asked to log in.

Another way although I'm not sure it can be done with different domain names is using sessions.  Since they are all on the same machine it might be possible but I'm not 100% sure on that one.

Comment: Sessions expire when hitting a different domain name, even sub-domains.

Comment: This works. However, what happens if someone copies a legitimate (and encrypted) token from website A, open website B in another browser/computer and post the (encrypted) token?

Comment: You could use some computer / browser information in the encrypted value that then when decrypt you validate that the person is still on the same machine.  Posting it over SSL should have another layer of encryption.

Comment: Another option can you implement OAuth like smirnov recommended.

Comment: Another option since they are all running under the same IIS setup and on the same servers why not setup the cart up as a virtual directory under the main site? Then you don't have to worry sending data over the wire. This may require some rework but might be the easiest solution going forward.

Comment: I thought about having subdomains but this would require to change 100 sites and it will probably do not work because of mix of http and https. If all sites could be changed to https then this should work.

Comment: why wouldn't it work?  The site can run both and you only do HTTPS on any of the cart pages or any page where a customer is transferring sensitive data.  I have all my sites running on this model right now only 3 but at one time I had around 75 running like this and it worked great.  Yes it would be a change to all the sites but would solve your security issues.  They wouldn't need to be subdomains and if your cart links are part of the config the changes would be minimal. You would setup the virtual directory in IIS (not subdomain) and change the config.

Answer (score 1):

Pass-port based authentication is a centralized authentication service provided by Microsoft that offers a single logon and core profile services for member sites. For more information, see the following Microsoft Web site:

[Passport Authentication Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8e50t0f%28vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: The Passport authentication is obsolete and has been superseded by Live ID. It would require a Live ID account which is different from what was asked here.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't implement a Single Sign-On at your infrastructure level, you should use [Identity Federation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_identity) which allows applications of different trusted party to share authentication through claims.

This can be done using [Security Assertion Markup Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) (SAML) directly or with products/standards like :

- [SimpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/)
- [Active Directory Federation Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx)

Also you can take a look at [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) or [OpenID](http://openid.net/) which are more shared authentication schemes than SSO or identity federation.