# Share session over multiple domain on same server

Tags: php, session, dns, share

Already lots of questions available regarding this. But there is no perfect answer I can find for me. So once again I am asking this question.

I want to share my session on multiple domains(**not sub domain**) like waht google.com is doing. When we login on google account at the same time we also login gmail.com, youtube.com and other google domains. And same when log out from any domain than also log out from every domain. This same functionality I want to do in my application.

With this functionality also there are some restrictions. I can not use database sessions.
Also I can not store cookie for any information.

Give me suggestions...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611545/preserving-session-variables-across-different-domains

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if store session in database.
Else it is unpossible. Server can't know about session from other server.

Comment: You are right, But I can't store any thing in database. Server is same but on different domain.

Comment: You can transfer SESSIONID in url, because can't read session from other domain. And read session on PHP, `session_start(SESSIONID)`

Comment: with out pass anything in url like we login in google.com, than after we enter new url like youtub.com  without pass anything already login.

Comment: You need create login server. User will be authorize use login server. And other servers can ask login server about user.

Comment: If you store session in DB, what is different ? How to select the good one ?