# How to send form post data to external url and then display them

Tags: php, ajax

Im creating a *pseudo payment system* where the user completes a form then the form redirects him to an external url  to complete the checkout process.

When the user submits the order details i want them to be passed along to the external url so i can display them sort of like a receipt.

**Question**

What's the best way of doing it?

Comment: Before knowing the best way, Shall we know the way that you have tried so far ?

Comment: I tried like normal processing $_POST variables but they dont seem to go through external url's

Comment: Do you want to pass some data to that external url and Do you know what are all the datas that is required by that external url ?

Comment: yes i just want to pass some form field data like some options the amount charged the name etc then i want them to be stored in my database and then redirect to the external url and just static display them in a div above the form that the user enters his payment details

Comment: yes that is ok, Is that external url also yours (or you know what data does that external url) requires ?

Comment: yes it is also mine and i can control it completely

Comment: Ok, then you shall try using  by ajax `crossDomain` request itself, Do you want me to help you in that ?

Comment: if you can yes please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of loading the page in `iframe` i would recommend you to do an ajax call to the external url (as you have control over it).

Here is the ajax for your operation

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'http://alexanderkap.esy.es/yourprojectfolder/file.php',
        crossDomain: true,
        data:'yourdata=anyofyourdata',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

**Note :**

1. You shall use any click event to call this ajax
2. To send your entire form data you shall use form serialize
3. I have just put the success and failure case in the console which you shall do that in a div

Comment: thanks a lot i will try that i am confident it will work

Comment: awesome i managed to do this  perfectly with your help. I wanted to ask something aditional though, when the payments checks and completes succesfully is there a way to redirect in my project's page get a variable that payment was completed succesfully and then run a query(update the user's info)

Comment: That's great, and yes it is possible by jquery and php. In php you shall do `header("Location: https://sitename.com/login.php");` and in jquery you shall do `$(location).attr('href','http://yourPage.com/');`  Together the url you shall pass the variable like ?id=1 like that and get the page to make it done.

Comment: And in the new page loading i will just check for get id if isset and if it is =success right? Thanks a lot by the way much appreciated

Comment: Yes, it is based on what you have done in the previous page. If you pass id in success case and if you dont pass id in fail case you need to check `isset` in the newly loading page.

Comment: awesome i thought it would be more complicated than this, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Thanks, everything is in what we think. Glad to help :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but if a user manually writes the id on the header then the query runs without him having to submit the form, so i thought of making an empty page acting as the middleman that received the id runs the query and then redirects to the site with just the sucess message :)

Comment: That's ok. :) Yes, you don't even have to do a middleman page, you can handle it in a function itself. And are you ok with that or you having any issue in it ??

Comment: yeah i did it with the way i told you how you could you do it in a function while preventing from users manually tampering with it since it is a url variable i am curious

Comment: You can do this in two ways one is by setting a `session` or `cookie` variable in the external page and in the new page you should check whether the session or cookie is set or not , If it is set then it is a success case and if not then it is a failure case. And the second way is to have a have table named as `transaction` or something and you will insert a random number in it for each transaction and whenever you taking the user to new page you should check whether the random number provided by the url and db are same if matches then success else failure

Comment: nice, i didnt knew you could pass session variables amongst external pages, i liked your second solution i will try it thanks a lot

Comment: You are welcome , And yes we can share session among external domains http://stackoverflow.com/a/14611577/3282633 and i have suggested you cookies also, but the second way is more secure :)