# Share PHP Session across domain (main and sub domain)

Tags: php, .htaccess, session

Suppose the domain I am working on is `www.example.com` and it has a link `shop` which takes the user to subdomain `shop.example.com`

Now on `shop.example.com` when user add product to cart the the cart information is stored in `$_SESSION['prd']` variable.

This session variable is available and `count` of cart items is perfectly displayed in `shop.example.com` but problem arises when i go to `example.com` then this `session` variable is not there.

I tried adding below line at the end of `.htaccess`

```
php_value session.cookie_domain ".example.com"
```

but this gives 500 error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preserving session variables across different domains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611545/preserving-session-variables-across-different-domains)

Comment: @saty This should be a lot easier since `shop.example.com` and `www.example.com` are on the same domain, and on the same server.

Comment: @Gags Go to your Apache error log and read what error it gives you. Internal server errors always log something that lets you figure out how to solve it.

Comment: how to access it on cpanel?

Answer (score 1):

As simple as it may seem did you try removing the quotes from around your subdomain?

```
php_value session.cookie_domain .example.com
```

I've not got the complete solution working yet, but this at least doesn't give any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, however, this solution was good for me, perhaps will help others in the future

edit you php.ini

> session.cookie_domain = ".exemple.com"

or in you script php

> session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');
>
> session_start();

if you have problems try add this in your php.ini

> suhosin.session.cryptdocroot = Off
>
> suhosin.cookie.cryptdocroot = Off

Comment: Please, observe what and how to [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).