# maintain session among multiple sub domains

Tags: php, session-cookies, subdomain

I have domains like:

- www.domain.com
- countyName1.domain.com
- countryName2.domain.com

All these domains are using the same directory files `/public_html`. I want to share session among all these domains.

I already tried these:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );
session_start();

OR

$some_name = session_name("some_name");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.some_domain.com',false,false);
session_start();
```

But none of them seems to be working for me.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserving session variables across different domains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611545/preserving-session-variables-across-different-domains)

Comment: @FMashiro Hi, i have the same domain name

Comment: can you try to make two files, with the same code:
`ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );
session_start();`
and then `var_dump($_SESSION);` to see what is actually inside of the session?

Comment: No. I have not used two files. Because i need to share session among all domain, whether session created from first domain or second or third. But, i used something like this 
`if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    var_dump($_SESSION);
}else{
    ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain.com' );
}`

Comment: ok, try making a file "test.php" that is accessible on the sites.
In that file, put this code: 
`ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
die();`

Now, go to www.domain.com/test.php and countyName1.domain.com/test,php and show us what you get on both sites

Comment: in logged-in domain i.e 'www.domain.com', I got this:

`array(16) { ["start"]=> int(1494320622) ["id"]=> int(97) ["Error_msg"]=> string(0) "" ["logged"]=> int(1) ["first_name"]=> string(6) "kumari" ["last_name"]=> string(7) "manisha"  ["active"]=> string(1) "1" ["blocked"]=> int(1) ["verified"]=> string(1) "1" ["mobile_verified"]=> int(1) ["account_disable"]=> int(0) ["userImage"]=> int(578) ["cid"]=> int(97) ["entity"]=> int(1) ["viewMode"]=> string(1) "0" }`

While for other subdomain I am getting 
`array(2) { ["start"]=> int(1494320056) ["id"]=> NULL}`

Comment: have you tried the second approach without the last two arguments?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143758/discussion-between-fmashiro-and-kumari-manisha).