# How to use PHP session when using the app from another domain through

Tags: php, session, iframe

I have created a web app for my customer and its working perfectly on my domain / server. But when I use this app from his domain through *Iframe* I cannot log in properly because I have this code in every page

```html
session_start();

 if(!$_SESSION['u_name']){

 header('location:login.php?logout=Sei disconnesso');

 }
```

So from his domain session part is not working properly. It redirects me always on the login page but when I use this from my domain it works perfectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserving session variables across different domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611545/preserving-session-variables-across-different-domains)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, the best way of doing this is [storing sessions in a database](http://php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php).

Comment: Can you explain it please, Or share any post.