# How to set a session variable for another website without user intercepting the variable?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have two sites: A.com and B.com. When a user lands on A.com I want to save a session variable for that user that is accessible from B.com. A.com and B.com are hosted on the same server.

The transmission must be secure. Meaning, there should be no way for the user to access that session variable.

I am using PHP.

Comment: This question contain similar issue:[check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611545/preserving-session-variables-across-different-domains)

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a session variable in A.com and B.com with same notation and get the values of the session of A.com in B.com

Comment: It's not specified answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cookie and save your value using any encryption. Have the key on both the sites to decrypt the value.