# Laravel share session across domain

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I'm currently working on a laravel project that is hosted on a domain. A part of this application, some functionality, has to be on a different domain. I found a way, in my web.php, I mapped all routes with the :

```
Route::group(['domain' => config('app.main_domain')], function () {
```

and the routes that need to be on the other domain in the same manner, but with a different domain. Ok.
In the main domain, I create an image with the src attribute:

```
<img src="{{ config('second_domain') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR }}auth?id={{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::encrypt(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::getId()) }}" style="display:none;"/>
```

pointing to this method route :

```
  if ($request->has('id')) {

            $session_id = Crypt::decrypt($request->get('id'));
            Session::setId($session_id);
            Session::start();
        }
```

It's working. I share the same session over different domain, but, I would like to ask you guys if you know a better method for this case scenario. I know this is an old method that google used.

I have to say that the users need to remain authenticated in the different domain. I have looked at laravel passport, or laravel sanctum, but those are for API authenticating.

Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: Please look into this, all the scenarios discussed in this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611545/preserving-session-variables-across-different-domains

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that's a very old thread, I read it, but didn't find anything that should help me..

Comment: When user login into site, redirect user to other website page with session id/some token and other website can read the sessionid/token, verify the token/id and if valid then set the cokkie and redirect back to wherever you initially want user to go after login.Look the accepted answer here 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761415/how-to-set-a-cookie-for-another-domain

Comment: It's kinda bad to redirect the user to another page after they log in, and then back to the original website.. I don't know if oauth2 will help me or guzzle requests

Comment: but that what google do , it redirect for very short while and fast that you dnt even notice. you can try storing token in local storage and other website can pick that up

Answer (score 0):

For logging in different domains you should describe different "guards".

---

## Configs

For example config/auth.php

```php
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web', // or 'admin'
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

```php
'guards' => [
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'tourists',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

I use two guards in my project:

- First one is 'admin', it's for admin panel and I use as provider User.php model.
- Second one is 'web', it's for frontend or public site, use Tourist.php model, but you can use User model as well.

---

## Controllers

You can use specific guard, In LoginController for admin panel:

```php
protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('admin');
}
```

And for general domain of website

```php
protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('web');
}
```

---

## Routes

And finally you do ask me, How can I protect my routes, pfff, simply:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:web'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'Cabinet\HomeController@index')->name('home');
});
```

Or for admin private routes

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'Admin\HomeController@index')->name('home');
});
```

Read more about authentication https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#adding-custom-guards

Comment: What is the purpose of different guards..? I thought my question was clear: I have an Laravel app that runs on dev.test. A part of this app, has to point to dev.test2, a different domain, when you go to dev.test2, you don't have a session