# Redirect if Active Session

Tags: javascript, php, html

Our sales page is on a .com domain and on there we have a "Login" link that points to the web portal which is on a different server using a .net domain.

If someone comes to .com and already has an active session with the .net, how can we automatically redirect them to the main .net page so that they do not have to click "Login"?

Thanks.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14611577/13246101

Comment: Thank you @Maneesh Babu M for your help with this.  I appreciate it greatly.