# Single Sign On in Django

Tags: python, django, single-sign-on

Regards

I,m workig in a django development with at least 4 apps, where every app have is own domain, the idea is centralize a **Single Sign On** to this 4 apps with a central db and central login panel, when a user login in the main login panel could be redirect to any of the other apps without login again.

Also I need when the user logout, the logout works for all apps.

I have been researchign and found django-sso and try to implement but doesn't work, could anybody help me wiht this.

How can I achieve this ??

Comment: This is not a question. Please ask about a particular error or problem you're having with django-sso, or what is the best package to use for SSO in Django.

Comment: @AlisonR. If you don't think it's a real question, go ahead and flag it as such (if you haven't already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is with a cookie that is somehow shared across different domains. As this is exactly the thing that a cookie by itself will never alow, you'll need some magic in between. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263010/whats-your-favorite-cross-domain-cookie-sharing-approach) post for some ideas