# A way for multiple websites to communicate

Tags: asp.net, .net, cookies, web

I need to control cookies on our website so a panel appeares asking if the user accepts to our terms for dropping cookies on their PC. This is fine but the problem is we use third party websites for sections in our website. I understand they will have to develop a similar tool to my website to comply with the new law but I don't want the user to have to agree to the use of cookies on each site (it makes it very frustrating for the customer). I'm trying to make it so that a user clicks accept on our website and then doesn't have to do the same for the third party websites based on some shared variable.

My question is what methods or options can I use to achieve this? I tried using cookies ( if the user accepts) but cookies can only be read by their own domain so this is ruled out.

Thanks

Comment: Are you displaying data from third parties through iframes?

Comment: No, the site actually goes to another domain that hosts a page that provides a particular service. They use tools to mimic the look and feel of our site so the customer has a better exprience and doesn't get lost. So they actually leave our website all together. We do own the third party software but due to the nature of the tools ( provide travel routes) we can't host it on our server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about cross domain cookies. You can not share your cookies across domains, but there are workaround. There is an interesting article which gives you an idea how Facebook does it: http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2010/08/how-facebook-sets-and-uses-cross-domain-cookies/

Additional reading here:

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_internet/article.php/c19417/Sharing-Cookies-Across-Domains.htm

[What's your favorite cross domain cookie sharing approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263010/whats-your-favorite-cross-domain-cookie-sharing-approach)