# Is it possible to share a cookie cross-site?

Tags: javascript, http, cookies

The question is simple.
e.g.: How does Google do when you login on mail.google.com (google.com domain), and then you go to youtube.com and your Google account is already open.

Thank You.

Comment: you can use domain names like `.google.com` so all sites with host name ending with `.google.com` will get these cookies

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263010/whats-your-favorite-cross-domain-cookie-sharing-approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When logging in to Gmail, a redirect first takes you to `https://accounts.google.com.au/accounts/SetSID?...` and then to `https://accounts.youtube.com/accounts/SetSID?...` so two separate sets of cookies are set. Then another redirect gets you back to Gmail. Same thing happens on logging out.

If you then delete all cookies for `youtube.com`, you will still be logged in to Gmail but not Youtube.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't notice it was that rudimentary.